# Xcode: Is it possible to have files available to all projects within a workspace?

Tags: ios, xcode-workspace

I have added a JSON file to the workspace, outside of any projects. I would like this file to be available to all projects that I add to the workspace.

When I try to do the following, I get a Cocoa Error 258:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"json"];


NSError *error;
NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

What's the proper way of sharing a single file in a workspace across many projects?

Answer (score 0):

At the target in your project there are 6 tabs. Go to build phases and check at Copy Bundle Resource whether or not that file is added to your new targets bundle.

Comment: Yeah, that works for when the file is in a single project. I kind of wanted that file to be available to all projects within the workspace, so I tried adding it outside of any projects, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Sorry it was already late. I would add the project. Put the single file in some kind of Target and add that target as a build dependency in the other project.